# minor errors in published paper

Tags: publications, errors-erratum, science

I am inexperienced in publishing papers in scientific journals. I was going over recently published paper of mine and found that I accidentally reported mean with standard deviation when I meant to report mean with standard error. The correct standard error is shown in a figure in the paper but I am wondering if I should contact the editor to make the correction.

Comment: Hi wanderwall, welcome to Academia.SE! It looks like you've written a good first question, but I think it's a little too similar to the question I asked a few years ago. I hope the answers there can help you! The upshot is, if it substantially changes the meaning of your work, then you should contact the editor(s), otherwise, let it slide :)

Comment: If no one contacts you, don’t worry & move on. If someone does write to you or the editor then deal with it then. Until then focus on other things.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am a perfectionist and I notice many errors in this paper. The message doesn't change, but I am disappointed for being sloppy. I will learn to be more careful in the future.

Comment: @wanderwall do not overthink. even in highly cited papers, there are little mistakes. it is normal.